# How to align an element at the bottom of this variable size flex element

Tags: css, flexbox

In [this](https://jsfiddle.net/dkam/ac7rybte/26/) jsfiddle, I want the Author element to be aligned between the various card elements.  I can't see how to stretch the element containing the details to match the variably sized elements in the same row.

The goal is to have the Author lines lining up horizontally across the rows.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  margin: 10px;
}

.card {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.product_detail {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid pink;
}

.detail_item {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  flex: 1;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class="card">
    <section>
      <img src="https://c.booko.info/covers/34edd12eb5c21388/v/600.jpeg" itemprop="image" size="500x750">
    </section>
    <section class="product_detail">
      <div itemprop="name" class='detail_item'>
        <a href="https://booko.info">A Book Title</a>
      </div>
      <div class="detail_item">A Subtitle might be here</div>
      <div itemprop="author" class='detail_item'>Author</div>
    </section>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <section>
      <img src="https://c.booko.info/covers/34edd12eb5c21388/v/600.jpeg" itemprop="image" size="500x750">
    </section>
    <section class="product_detail">

      <div itemprop="name" class='detail_item'>
        <a href="https://booko.info">A Book Title which is much longer and takes up a few lines</a>
      </div>
      <div class="detail_item">A Subtitle might be here</div>
      <div itemprop="author" class='detail_item'>Author</div>
    </section>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <section>
      <img src="https://c.booko.info/covers/34edd12eb5c21388/v/600.jpeg" itemprop="image" size="500x750">
    </section>
    <section class="product_detail">
      <div itemprop="name" class='detail_item'>
        <a href="https://booko.info">A Book Title</a>
      </div>
      <div class="detail_item">A Subtitle might be here</div>
      <div itemprop="author" class='detail_item'>Author</div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You want to stretch the details match to the other details? so that they will look like have the same height?

Comment: @indefinite yes that's right - I'd like the author names to line up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understood it, you are trying to have the Author div anchored to the bottom of each card.

Assuming I understood correctly, you were pretty close. Here's what was missing:

1. the `.card` div needed to be a flex container
2. the `.product_detail` section needed to stretch to fill its available space
3. the Author div needed to be anchored to the bottom

Here's the CSS that changed:

```css
.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.product_detail {
  flex: 1;
}

.detail_item[itemprop="author"] {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

Here's an [updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tk31gy8b/)

---

Note: if you don't want the `.detail_item` divs to be vertically evenly distributed, you can just remove the `flex: 1;` property from `.detail_item` which would look [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/h9bckp84/).

Hope this helps. Good luck!